# Prevent browser URL from changing during page redirect in an SSL configuration using IBM HTTP server

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

I have installed ibmhttp server as a plugin in websphere application server. I also configured httpd.conf file to allow for ssl connections and this serves the application as expected, however, two issues arise:

I noticed that after entering the URL to launch my app @ https://localhost/application-name, it redirects to the URL specified in the application's configuration. What I want is to have the https://localhost/application-name url, while the content of the application is served without changing the url to the application's configuration URL
I want to be able to type in the browser's URL address bar only the application-name and the URL should change to the localhost
For the httpd.conf file, after enabling the SSL module by uncommenting the  LoadModule ibm_ssl_module modules/mod_ibm_ssl.so and Listen 0.0.0.0:443,

I have the following virtual host declaration

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
     SSLEnable
     SSLProtocolDisable SSLv2
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost localhost:443>
     SSLEnable
     SSLProtocolDisable SSLv2
    </VirtualHost>

    KeyFile "C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/HTTPServer/ihskey.kdb"
    SSLDisable
```

Comment: This is not the part of the configuration that's responsible of your redirect. Find the configuration that does the current redirection. If you can't figure it out by yourself, we could then help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

When you find the rewrite config then you will need to add the passthrough|PT option to the rewrite rule.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt